# Javascript Websocket timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ovh

I'm working on small app using node.js and basic html/js web page.

On localhost, I have no problem, webSocket works as well, but when I try on my dedicated server (ovh/kimsufi server), my websocket client return timeout error :

On my server :

ws.js :

```
var http = require('http'),
WebSocket = require('ws'),
WebSocketServer = WebSocket.Server;
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen('3005', '0.0.0.0', function() {
     console.log('Listening on ' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
   var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});
    wss.on('connection', function(client){
        console.log('connected');
        client.on('message', function(message) {
            client.send('received');
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Result on Linux console :

> -----@-----:~/---/---/nodeServer$ node ws.js Listening on 0.0.0.0:3005

On my client :

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://------.---:3005");
});
```

Result in chrome/firefox console :

> comm.js:12 WebSocket connection to 'ws://------.---:3005/' failed:
>   Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I think this error apears when I did a new virtualHost, can it block the websocket ?

Comment: Run a netstat command to make sure port 3005 in bound to a node process

Comment: tcp        0      0 *:3000                  *:*                     LISTEN      lemazo     1262011     17306/node

Comment: I changed port 3005 to 3000 on all files, I have node on netstat -alptue

Comment: Are you (as a client) behind a proxy ?

Comment: Oh ! Yes, I did'nt think about it ...
You're right, I'm behind a proxy, that's working on my smartphone.

Thanks !